Short story - disease that causes deformities and telepathy. Bar joke
This is a story from Asimovs in the 1980s; the backstory is a disease that causes disfiguring growths on the face/head and the ability to read minds. The telepaths are a mistreated minority (I forget the disparaging nickname). I think the story involves one of these telepaths at a bar, telling a bitter variation  of the horse-walked-into-a-bar joke, something like: the bartender says, "don't see many of your type come in here", and the telepath says, "You're cheating on your wife, and want to kill me, and besides, with these prices, you won't see many"

This is one of two stories published by Scott Elliot Marbach, "The Eternity Wave" published only in Asimov's, May 1983.

I let the door fall closed behind me. "There was this bonehead," I said. "And he walks into a bar and orders Scotch neat. And the bartender serves it up and says, 'that'll be twenty-seven fifty.' So the bonehead pays up, and while he's sitting there nursing the drink the barkeep decides to get friendly. 'We don't see many boneheads in here,' he says. The bonehead closes his eyes for a minute, like he's thinking. Then he finishes his drink and he says: 'You're cheating on your wife, you're wearing women's underwear, you water the whiskey, and when you saw me walk in here, you quadrupled the price of the drink. And, at these prices, you won't see many more.'"

You can read the story at the Internet Archive.

How did you find it so quickly, btw?

Text search at the Internet Archive; it's possible to just search Asimov's issues, and by picking the correct set of words from your remembered quote.  (I actually didn't start with "You're cheating on your wife," since accurately remembering verb tenses can be tricky, though in retrospect I should have.)

Or don't bother; it's fun to look these stories up and read/reread them. :D  (I had an Analog subscription, and would swap with a friend who was getting Asimov's, but we weren't organized, so I didn't see all the issues and I didn't have a chance to reread them.)

P.S.  I guess this is a good example of how a small detail (the joke) is helpful in finding the story.
